# Get all permutations of a field of nested object structure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have the following object and it is just an example as the depth can be more than that, there could be more Objects than 1 in all of the Nexts, the objective is to extract the permutations of all Vals given the structure:

```
const config = {
 Next: [
    {
      Val: 11,
      Next: [
        {
          Val: 21,

          Next: [
            {
              Val: 31,
              Next: [
                {
                  Val: 42,
                },
                {
                  Val: 43,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              Val: 32,
              Next: [
                {
                  Val: 41,
                },
                {
                  Val: 42,
                },
                {
                  Val: 43,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

The output should be an array of arrays and the order DOES matter:

```
[
  [11, 21, 31, 42],
  [11, 21, 31, 43],
  [11, 21, 32, 41],
  [11, 21, 32, 42],
  [11, 21, 32, 43]
]
```

I have tried implementing some kind of a recursion, but I am unable to get the correct output:

```
let combinations = [];

const getNextItems = (nextItems) => {
  let subarray = [];

  nextItems.Next.forEach(item => {
    subarray.push(item.Val);
    item.Next && getNextItems(item)
  });
 
  combinations.push(subarray);
}

getNextItems(config);   

console.log(combinations);
```

And instead I get:

```
[
  [42, 43],
  [41, 42, 43],
  [31, 32],
  [21],
  [11],
]
```

I am sensing that I am on the right track since these are the correct values, just that instead of permutations, its just giving me arrays of all items from each level.

EDIT: Moving the subarray out of the recursion gave me the first correct permutation, but not the rest:

```
let combinations = [];
let subarray = [];

const getNextItems = (nextItems) => {    
  nextItems.Next.forEach(item => {
    subarray.push(item.Val);
    item.Next && getNextItems(item)
    combinations[robotName].push(subarray);
    subarray = [];
  });  
}
```

The result is:

```
[
  [11, 21, 31, 42],
  [43],
  [],
  [32, 41],
  [42],
  [43],
  [],
  [],
  [],
]
```

And there is a pattern that in a way gives me the permutations just not in the way I want them :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach and collect all values from all depths.

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes an array and performs an operation with a temporary result. In this case the *`startValue`* is an array. For each element of the array it takes a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of `Val` and `Next` and checks if a nested array exist.

If so get the values from this array and theit children. To add a new array to the result set it need to add the actual `Val` as well.

If not just add a wrapped `Val` to the result set.

```js
const
    getValues = array => array.reduce((r, { Val, Next }) => {
        if (Next) r.push(...getValues(Next).map(a => [Val, ...a]));
        else r.push([Val]);
        return r;
    }, []),
    config = { Next: [{ Val: 11, Next: [{ Val: 21, Next: [{ Val: 31, Next: [{ Val: 42 }, { Val: 43 },], }, { Val: 32, Next: [{ Val: 41 }, { Val: 42 }, { Val: 43 }] }] }] }] },
    result = getValues(config.Next);

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: However I am not that familiar with .reduce yet, could you briefly explain exactly how the code works please?

Comment: @Darkbound, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a straightforward recursion and a `flatMap` call.  Here's one way:

```js
const getCombos = ({Val, Next}, path = []) =>
  Val && !Next
    ? [[... path, Val]]
    : (Next || []) .flatMap (o => getCombos (o, [... path, ... (Val ? [Val] : []) ]))


const config ={Next: [{Val: 11, Next: [{Val: 21, Next: [{Val: 31, Next: [{Val: 42}, {Val: 43}]}, {Val: 32, Next: [{Val: 41}, {Val: 42}, {Val: 43}]}]}]}]}

console .log (getCombos (config))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by defining an empty path.  This will hold our final result, and at intermediate times it might be empty, or might look like `[11]` or like `[11, 21, 32]`, etc.  Then, if `Val` exists on the object, but we don't have `Next`, we return an array with one path on it, the current path plus `Val`.  Otherwise, for every element in `Next` we recur on the element, passing either the existing path if `Val` doesn't exist or the current path plus `Val`, combining the results into one array using `flatMap`.

This is fairly naive.  If `Val` might contain a false-y value you want to include in your output (perhaps `0`), then you would need to change the test for `Val`.  We could do that and something more robust for missing `Next` properties by rewriting like this:

```js
const getCombos = ({Val = undefined, Next = []}, path = []) =>
  Val !== undefined && !Next.length
    ? [[... path, Val]]
    : (Next || []) .flatMap (o => getCombos (o, [... path, ... (Val ? [Val] : []) ]))
```

But I would suggest sticking to the first version unless you need these additional features.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a new function for accomplishing the above task.

The function works on principle of collecting the combinations from the **Child Objects** and then forming new combination for the **Current Object** and returning the same.

```js
let combinations = [];

const getCombinations = (parentObject) => {
  var childCombinationList = [];

  if(parentObject.Next != undefined) {
    parentObject.Next.forEach((item) => {
      childCombinationList = childCombinationList.concat(getCombinations(item));
    });
  }

  if(parentObject.Val != undefined) {
    var newCombinationList = [];

    if(childCombinationList.length > 0) {
      childCombinationList.forEach((childCombination) => {
        var newCombination = [parentObject.Val];

        newCombination = newCombination.concat(childCombination);
        newCombinationList.push(newCombination);
      });
    }
    else {
      newCombinationList = [[parentObject.Val]];
    }

    return newCombinationList;
  }
  else {
    return childCombinationList;
  }
}

config = { Next: [{ Val: 11, Next: [{ Val: 21, Next: [{ Val: 31, Next: [{ Val: 42 }, { Val: 43 },], }, { Val: 32, Next: [{ Val: 41 }, { Val: 42 }, { Val: 43 }] }] }] }] },

combinations = getCombinations(config);   

console.log(combinations);
```